# ¿Cómo puedo retornar el slash command de Slack en Apex Salesforce con el SDK de Slack en Apex?

Tags: sdk, apex, slack-api, salesforce

estoy trabajando con el [SDK de Slack en Salesforce con Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk/guide/overview.html) para manejar los Slash Commands donde deseo que haya persistencia de lo que el usuario pregunta (/test create a new channel) esto quiero que se mantenga como un mensaje y posteriormente que el Bot/App responda a este mensaje por medio de hilo (el manejo del hilo ya lo tengo listo), pero según la documentación de Slack [Slack Slash Interactivity](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands) hay un apartado que dice que el `response_type` debe ser `in_channel` pero dado que no manejo peticiones HTTP con este SDK no sé en que parte debo agregar esto para lograr mi objetivo, agradezco cualquier ayuda

```
public class SlashCommandCall extends Slack.SlashCommandDispatcher {

public override Slack.ActionHandler invoke(Slack.SlashCommandParameters parameters, Slack.RequestContext context) {
    return Slack.ActionHandler.ack(new Handler(parameters, context));
}

public class Handler implements Slack.RunnableHandler {
    Slack.SlashCommandParameters parameters;
    Slack.RequestContext context;

    public Handler(Slack.SlashCommandParameters parameters, Slack.RequestContext context){
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void run () {
        System.debug(context);
        System.debug(parameters);
        Slack.App app = Slack.App.App.get();
        Slack.BotClient botClient = app.getBotClientForTeam(this.context.getTeamId());
        String channel = context.getChannelId();
        String slashCommandParameterValue = parameters.getText();

        Slack.ChatPostMessageResponse response = botClient.chatPostMessage(
                Slack.ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().channel(channel).text('*' + parameters.getCommand() + '* ' + slashCommandParameterValue).build()
        );

        String animalName = APICalls.getAnimalNameById(Integer.valueOf(slashCommandParameterValue));

        String postMessageThreadTs = response.getTs();
        botClient.chatPostMessage(
                Slack.ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().channel(channel).text(animalName).threadTs(postMessageThreadTs).build()
        );


        if (response.getError() != null) {
            System.debug(response.getError());
        } else {
            System.debug('success');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Lo que hace esta parte de código es leer el comando y el texto y devolver en forma de mensaje a Slack, pero es el bot/app quien escribe el mensaje, y no el usuario. [Slack Post Message](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)